# Using matrix operations to wrap arrays

Tags: linear-algebra, maple

I'm coding with Maple and I need an efficient way to wrap arrays of numbers to different dimensions.  For example, let $A$ be the 3x5 matrix listing the numbers 1-15 in order, and $B$ be the 5x3 matrix of the same numbers.  Is there an easy way to relate these two matrices in terms of matrix algebra?

Comment: I think you're looking for a function or operator that will be called reshape

Comment: Do you want to vectorize the matrices? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_%28mathematics%29

Answer (score 1):

Leaving aside the question of relating the matrices using matrix algebra, if you simply want to reshape the matrix of values in Maple you have a couple of options:

In the [ArrayTools](https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=ArrayTools) package, you can use the [Reshape](https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=ArrayTools/Reshape) command to copy the original data to a new matrix with the specified shape. The [Alias](https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=ArrayTools/Alias) command can also provide a different view (shape) of the data and does not create a copy of the underlying data, however if you do change the underlying data, this may have some adverse effects. Note that neither of these commands change the underlying order of the elements. Here's an example:

```
data := Array(seq([1..15]));
A := ArrayTools:-Reshape(data, [3,5]);
B := ArrayTools:-Reshape(data, [5,3]);
```